# Python Comparing String returning not equal when they really are

Tags: python, string

I have a dictionary (B) where the value is a list. This code is not giving me the expected results:

```
print(type(B[Bkey][1]))
print(type(B[Bkey][6].upper()+' '+B[Bkey][7].upper()))
print(B[Bkey][1])
print(B[Bkey][6].upper()+' '+B[Bkey][7].upper())
print(B[Bkey][6].upper()+' '+B[Bkey][7].upper() == B[Bkey][1])
print(B[Bkey][6].upper()+' '+B[Bkey][7].upper().strip() == B[Bkey][1].strip())
```

This is the print out:

```
<class 'str'>
<class 'str'>
MY STRING
MY STRING
False
False
```

The weird thing is that the dictionary is pretty big (approx. 3000 items) and the same comparison for most of the items returns TRUE but it returns FALSE for a few of the items??

Please help.

Comment: Show a [mcve]. You may have stray spaces or similar but unequal characters or something.

Comment: Try printing the `repr` of the strings, and see if they are really the same.

Comment: Try to print something like `print("|" + B[Bkey][1] + "|")` and `print("|" + B[Bkey][6].upper()+' '+B[Bkey][7].upper() + "|")`, maybe there is some whitespace at the end.

Comment: also try this one? print(B[Bkey][6].upper().strip()+' '+B[Bkey][7].upper().strip() == B[Bkey][1].strip())

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers. After I posted the question I realized maybe the space in the string was the issue. So I tried the following:

```
print((B[Bkey][6].upper()+' '+B[Bkey][7].upper()).split(' '))
print(B[Bkey][1].split(' '))
```

and got this:

```
['MY', 'STRING']
['MY\xa0STRING']
```

A quick search led to this answer:

```
string = string.replace(u'\xa0',u'')
```